# Invalid parameter number - PDO error

Tags: php, pdo

Please do not castigate me for asking a question that has been asked many times. I have spent hours ploughing through answers but cannot find a solution to mine. I am just learning to use PDO. I have successfully used it to select from a database and display results but I am having a problem with the Update function.

I get the error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

I have checked and rechecked my code but no typos spring out at me, so maybe it has something to do with the edit_date field? If anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful as I have spent hours researching and experimenting with  no solution. Regards  Tog.

here is the code:

```
  $article_id = (trim ( $_POST [ 'id' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR:no ID' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'id' ] );
    $article_id = (INT) $article_id;
    $title = (trim ( $_POST [ 'title' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter a Title' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'title' ] );
            $author = (trim ( $_POST [ 'author' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter an Author name' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'author' ] );
            $image_url = (trim ( $_POST [ 'image_url' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter an Image URL' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'image_url' ] );
            $main_article = (trim ( $_POST [ 'main_article' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter some article content' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'main_article' ] );
            $snippet = (trim ( $_POST [ 'snippet' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter snippet text' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'snippet' ] );
            $friendly_url = (trim ( $_POST [ 'friendly_url' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter a friendly url' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'friendly_url' ] );
            $meta_title = (trim ( $_POST [ 'meta_title' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter a Meta Title' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'meta_title' ] );
            $meta_description = (trim ( $_POST [ 'meta_description' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: Enter a Meta Description' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'meta_description' ] );
            $edited_by = (trim ( $_POST [ 'edited_by' ]) == ' ') ? die ( 'ERROR: who edited this?' ) : mysql_escape_string ( $_POST [ 'edited_by' ] );
            $edit_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=gosport", $username, $password);
        /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
        echo 'Connected to database<br />';
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        /*** Update data ***/
       $sql = "UPDATE sport SET title = :title, 
                author = :author, 
                image_url = :image_url,  
                main_article = :main_article,  
                snippet = :snippet,
                edit_date = :edit_date,
                friendly_url = :friendly_url,
                meta_title = :meta_title,
                meta_description = :meta_description,
                edited_by = : edited_by
                WHERE article_id = :article_id";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);                                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':image_url', $image_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':main_article', $main_article, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':snippet', $snippet, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':edit_date', $edit_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':friendly_url', $friendly_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':meta_title', $meta_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':meta_description', $meta_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':edited_by', $edited_by, PDO::PARAM_STR);  

    $stmt->execute(); 
             /*** close the database connection ***/
        $dbh = null;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Thanks for the replies. I have made some changes accordingly and no longer get an error message but when I run the code it does not update the database. Everything stays the same as it was before I run the code.

My new code:

```
$article_id = (trim ( $_POST [ 'id' ]) == ' ');
$article_id = (INT) $article_id;
$title = (trim ( $_POST [ 'title' ]) == ' ');
$author = (trim ( $_POST [ 'author' ]) == ' ');
 $image_url = (trim ( $_POST [ 'image_url' ]) == ' ');
$main_article = (trim ( $_POST [ 'main_article' ]) == ' ');
$snippet = (trim ( $_POST [ 'snippet' ]) == ' ');
$friendly_url = (trim ( $_POST [ 'friendly_url' ]) == ' ');
$meta_title = (trim ( $_POST [ 'meta_title' ]) == ' ');
$meta_description = (trim ( $_POST [ 'meta_description' ]) == ' ');
$edited_by = (trim ( $_POST [ 'edited_by' ]) == ' ');
$edit_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=gosport", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    /*** Update data ***/
   $sql = "UPDATE sport SET title = :title, 
            author = :author, 
            image_url = :image_url,  
            main_article = :main_article,  
            snippet = :snippet,
            edit_date = :edit_date,
            friendly_url = :friendly_url,
            meta_title = :meta_title,
            meta_description = :meta_description,
            edited_by = :edited_by
            WHERE article_id = :article_id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':article_id', $article_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                       
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':author', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':image_url', $image_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':main_article', $main_article, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':snippet', $snippet, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':edit_date', $edit_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':friendly_url', $friendly_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':meta_title', $meta_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam('meta_description', $meta_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':edited_by', $edited_by, PDO::PARAM_STR);  

$stmt->execute(); 
         /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
   {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: Sure, I can see 11 placeholders in your SQL and only 10 parameters bound. Where are you binding `:article_id`?

Comment: All those calls to `mysql_real_escape_string()` are unnecessary and invalid in this context. No escaping is needed, as PDO will handle that when binding parameters. `mysql_real_escape_string()` can only function anyway with an active connection via `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Mixing MySQL APIs. Unlike *gin & tonic*, those `mysql_` and PDO just don't.

Comment: Also note that `trim($_POST['xxxxx']) == ' '` will always be `false`, so your checks for empty fields (I assume...) are flawed / will not work. You can use `empty()` instead.

Comment: `= : edited_by`? Will PHP even ignore that extra space and treat that as a parameter and not a wonky "equals colon undefined_field_name"?

Comment: @MarcB *Hm...*, interesting. I for one never tested for something like that before. Good point. I'm going to have to test that sometime.

Comment: @MarcB *"Will PHP even ignore that extra space and treat that as a parameter"* - No, it will throw `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': edited_by'` - No better way to find out *for sure* then with a quick test. *Now we know* ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a binding for `:article_id` in the WHERE clause. Thus you have a mismatching number of parameters between your prepared statement and the parameters passed upon execution.

Also as noted in comments above, don't use "escape_string" type functions.  There are unnecessary with parametrized prepared statements and would, in fact, introduce unintended character escapes in the recorded data when you have cases where escape sequences would be encountered.

Also, here:

```
edited_by = : edited_by
```

You probably want to lose the space after the colon.  I honestly don't know if this would cause an error or not, but it is at least poor form.

Comment: Agreed, but Mike, look at OP's code again `mysql_escape_string` nothing's going to get entered in DB. OP doesn't need to use those, can just omit it altogether.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree that is a problem, but that is not actually THE problem causing the error message noted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added commentary to ditch use of string escapes as noted in comments above.

Comment: I saw that Mike, hence the +1 ;)

Comment: Marc made a good point regarding [`= : edited_by`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468022/invalid-parameter-number-pdo-error#comment41574460_26468022)

Comment: *"I honestly don't know if this would cause an error or not"* - No better way to test: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': edited_by'` ;)

Comment: I have made changes to the code per answers received (see new code above) and I am not getting an error message, but the database is not being updated at all. The records carry the same info after running the code as before. I did spot that the article_id field is PARAM_INT instead of PARAM_STR but changing that has made no difference. I still can't get it to update the database, even though there are no error messages. Connection to the Database is working OK.

Comment: OK the code works if I make the early variables `code`$title = $_POST [ 'title' ];`/code` etc. I couldn't find a way of checking if the fields were empty, but at least the update is working.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for testing the behavior of that malformed syntax and adding comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for that tip. answer has now been accepted